# Using UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, swiftyuserdefaults

If I run the following code in a Playground, it correctly prints out "here 1" However, if I run the code in my app using from a class function, it prints out "here". How do I correctly test if I have an array saved?

```
if let savedArray = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "MyKey") {
    print("here")
}
else {
    print("here 1")
}
```

Comment: are you sure you haven't saved some value for "MyKey" somewhere?

Comment: Yes. I am positive.

Comment: if it's printing only "here", then savedArray is not nil. What's its value at that point?

Comment: As far as I know, playgrounds run in a sandbox so I don't think it is possible to store user defaults persistently across executions, so it will always print "here 1".

Comment: If I print the array, () shows up in the console. If I cast it to a different type, [] shows up in the console. I am pretty sure I haven't set the value anywhere else.

Comment: I tried using a different value and it works. But I don't think I use "MyKey" anywhere else.

Comment: Delete the app from your device or simulator and then reinstall and  run it.